# How do I change images on a jQuery tab when the tab is active?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using jQuery tabs, and I am using images for each tab instead of text. I would like to change the images when the tab is active. The code for the tabs themselves is:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1"><img src="images/dashboard_off.gif"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2"><img src="images/advertising_off.gif"/></a></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3"><img src="images/marketing_off.gif"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4"><img src="images/office_off.gif"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-5"><img src="images/networking_off.gif"/></a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-6"><img src="images/education_off.gif"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to switch those to the "on" version of the image ("images/dashboard_on.gif" and so on).

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    event: "mouseover"
    });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any tabs plugin? If yes, which is it?

Comment: jQuery tabs:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
 event: "mouseover"
 });
 });
</script>`

Comment: Ah, jQueryUI tabs. Mouseover or click event?

Comment: The complete HTML would be helpful.

Comment: Would like to keep the mouseover event, but if I have to switch to click, that's okay. I just need the tab image to change when the tab is active.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an image inline, you might consider using a background image; that way, you can switch it out on `.ui-state-active`.

---

If you absolutely have to use an inline image, you could try this:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    })
    .find('> ul > li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('img').prop('src', function(i, v) {
            return v.replace('off.gif', 'on.gif');
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('img').prop('src', function(i, v) {
            return v.replace('on.gif', 'off.gif');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem, though, is that I need the "on" image to be more than just a hover effect. I need the script to recognize that the tab is active, not just that the mouse has hovered over.